# HTML/CSS - Calling peer tag for dropdown

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `<td>` tag having the same hierarchy level (called `<td>`1 and `<td>`2), and I want the `<td>`2 to show up when I click the `<td>`1. So far, I've only known about calling descendent tags for dropdown, not peer tags. Is it possible to do that? If it is, could you show me some way to do that? Here are my code:

```
<tr class="active-dropdown">
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
</tr>
<tr class="dropdown-menu">
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  display: none;
}
label{
  cursor: pointer;
}
#show_dropdown_menu{
  display: none;
}
#show_dropdown_menu:checked:not(:disabled) ~ .dropdown-menu{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="show_dropdown_menu" />
<label for="show_dropdown_menu">
<div class="active-dropdown">
  active-dropdown
</div>
</label>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  dropdown-menu
</div>
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with js，let the action bind events